# How do get separate digits from a string in Java?

Tags: java, replaceall

I 'am working on a file editor project and need to determine when a user inputs a number.

- If the user inputs D, it should delete the last line
- if they enter D 2 it will delete index 2
- if they enter D 2 5 then the program should delete lines 2 -5 from a
  the text file they are editing.

The issue I am having is how to determine when a user inputs two numbers. So far I have this

```
input = keyboard.nextLine();
String digit = input.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

    if(!(digit.equals(""))){
       n = Integer.parseInt(digit);
                        //and so on
    }
```

So if I enter **D 2 5** with this, the number is 25 and I need a way to get it to read 2 and 5 as separate numbers.

Comment: try using `String.split`

Comment: Can't you use the scanner nextXXX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

```
String s = "D 2 5";
String array[] = s.split(" ");
```

This splits the `String`, *by space*. Now, you can access the parts of it, using `array[index]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
 String myString = " d 5 6";
 Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
 List abc = new ArrayList();
 while (m.find()) 
 {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    abc.add(n);
 }     
 System.out.println(abc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string by one or more space

```
String[] digit = s.split(" +");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "     D    2     5";
        String array[] = str.replace(" ", "").split("");
        List<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String item : array) {
            try {
                numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(item));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***how to determine when a user inputs two numbers.***

you can take the user input and then validate against the string by checking the number of "parameters"

```
String input = "D 3 9";

String[] arrayParam = input.split(" ");

if(arrayParam.lenght==2){
    System.out.println("1 number only");
}elseif(arrayParam.lenght==3){
    System.out.println("2 numbers");
}else{
    System.out.println("invalid input");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using this for my method calls.